# What args should be used to make ls group file in such a way?

Tags: linux, file-management, bashrc

I'd like to list files grouped in such a sequence: **ALL** hidden files, directories, and the rest sorted by extension. So I made an alias in .bashrc like this:

alias ll="LC_COLLATE=C ls -AlhF --sort=extension --group-directories-first"

However this fails to put all the hidden files at first, only ending up sorting extension first and dot files second.

Any one can help me to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but there is a catch: a `.hidden` file is sorted as a `.hidden` extension, while a `.hidden.txt` file is sorted as a `.txt` (ahead of others `.txt`, because the empty string is sorted ahead...).